# Pre-poppulating dates with Date.js in MonthName, ##, #### format

Tags: javascript, jquery, datejs

I have to pre-populate two calendars with values. I need it to be in the format of January 16, 2012. Currently, I am using Date.js (http://www.datejs.com/).

I currently have:

```
var e = Date.today(),
    s = Date.today().add(-30).days();
```

These return `Mon Jan 16 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)` which is of no use to me. Either using Date.js or not (I don't care), how do I get the current date in the format I'm asking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Date.js offers formatting with its custom [`toString` method](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#toString):

```
var eFormatted = e.toString('MMMM dd, yyyy');
    sFormatted = s.toString('MMMM dd, yyyy');
```

You can see the full list of format specifiers at http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/FormatSpecifiers.

Answer (score 0):

```
Date.today().toString("mmmm dS, yyyy");
```

API Documentation: http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation